# How can I find out which certificate of push notifications is used in the application? XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have several certificates of push notifications in the developer.apple.com
I released the application, and in XCode I selected automatically manage signing.
How now to find out which of the two push-notification certificates Apple used to sign my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push notification certificates are not used to sign an application. Push certificates are used to sign and verify the push notification data sent to the APNS service itself - the data.

To find out which push notification certificates are associated with a specific application log into the Apple Developer Center website. Navigate to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" and then "App IDs". Check each app ID, you can see which SSL certificates are being used for push notifications (if any).

Your applications may be using the new token-based authentication keys instead of SSL certificates. Those are located in the "Keys" section of the Apple Developer Center website.